# How do I create a direct current with a magnet? The magnet is not to be moved in the direction of the wire

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

How do I create a direct current with a magnet? The magnet is not to be moved in the direction of the wire. In fact I'm looking for the contrary to the drawing from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RechteHand.png

[image: magnetic field]

Update

1st: The background is that in the German wiki under Magnetismus you find the sentence "Any movement of electric charges produces a magnetic field." For a wire this is proved by experiment, even a direct electrical current produces a magnetic field. This was illustrated in the drawing above. My first doubt is, do a number of free flowing electrons in the absence of any external fields produce a magnetic field in the same strength as in the wire. In this case I believe only experimental facts.

2nd: If a DC in a straight wire produces a magnetic field the reason for this must be the EM induction. But there are two strange facts. The EM induction connects always three components, two of them produces the third. This are the electrical current, the magnetic field and the movement of the wire or the magnetic field. But the straight wire in the wiki definition under point one does not moves.

To proof the wiki definition I remembered that the vector components of the EM induction are a cross product. This is the reason I ask help me to find out what is the reverse process of the above linked drawing.

Comment: It is still not very clear. You are asking the reverse of the image,  and it would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_DC_electric_motor#Permanent-magnet_motors . The magnets do not move, the wires do.

Comment: @anna, no doubt that a DC in the wire induces a magnetic field. This field has to be the cross product of the current and the movement of something. What is moving? The wire isn't. I imagine that the electrons except their movement in the wires direction will have collisions with the atoms and they will be accelerated. More than I imagine that the electrons acceleration (of course including the circular acceleration) is the only cause for the induction. I'm wrong if you can tell me that a electron beam induces the same magnetic field like the same amount of electrons in a wire.

Comment: Yes , electron beams induce magnetic fields. Simple experiment, a magnet next to a tube TV  which works with an electron beam. The beam is attracted to the magnets https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1xS-ssfTM8 Actually do not do it at home because you might also polarize the screen and leave a permanent coloration.

Comment: @anna v. In the picture there isn't any external magnetic field and my question was directed to this fact. The maximum we can do is to use a magnetic needle (a test device) to find the magnetic field of a electron beam.

Comment: Somebody could calculate the magnetic field of a electron beam and of the same flow of electrons in a wire?

Comment: Why? unless given as a problem in a graduate course? The electrons in a wire do not have the velocities of the electrons in a beam ( near light speed) , so it will only be a qualitative comparison. We know classical electricity and magnetism work to great precision and we only make the effort of calculation if it is necessary for constructing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I observe the image, question, and all physics, I see that the only logical answers are:
A-the copper is twisted or coiled, technically violating the rule of 'The magnet is not to be moved in the same direction'
OR
B-there is some sort of incline or slope on the N/S divider, but an offset, I'm guessing is also wrong (because the image is illustrated as perpendicular)
otherwise you are charging the copper vertically and since the copper is narrow and long the charge wouldn't be worth anything. this is, as far as my knowledge, impossible.